# Why do I get an exception when updating row on sqlite with monotouch?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.ios

I have a simple table and when I try to update row on SQLite, the application close and expose this exception:

```
Stacktrace:

  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) <0x000b7>
  at RemedioNaHora.Application.Main (string[]) <0x00017>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>

Native stacktrace:

    0   RemedioNaHora                       0x000908ec mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 284
    1   RemedioNaHora                       0x00005c88 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 248
    2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9365c59b _sigtramp + 43
    3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
    4   UIKit                               0x0219355a -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    5   UIKit                               0x02238b76 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    6   UIKit                               0x0223903f -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 503
    7   UIKit                               0x0238aa6c -[_UISwitchInternalView _sendActions] + 121
    8   Foundation                          0x0173786d __NSFireDelayedPerform + 389
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x01195966 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 22
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x01195407 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 551
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x010f87c0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1888
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x010f7db4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 212
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x010f7ccb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    14  GraphicsServices                    0x04789879 GSEventRunModal + 207
    15  GraphicsServices                    0x0478993e GSEventRun + 114
    16  UIKit                               0x02190a9b UIApplicationMain + 1175
    17  ???                                 0x0b5b9784 0x0 + 190551940
    18  ???                                 0x0b5b89d0 0x0 + 190548432
    19  ???                                 0x0b5b8878 0x0 + 190548088
    20  ???                                 0x0b5b8907 0x0 + 190548231
    21  RemedioNaHora                       0x00009ff2 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 722
    22  RemedioNaHora                       0x00169eee mono_runtime_invoke + 126
    23  RemedioNaHora                       0x0016dfd4 mono_runtime_exec_main + 420
    24  RemedioNaHora                       0x001733f5 mono_runtime_run_main + 725
    25  RemedioNaHora                       0x000671f5 mono_jit_exec + 149
    26  RemedioNaHora                       0x002116c9 main + 2825
    27  RemedioNaHora                       0x00003045 start + 53

=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

Does somebody know what happened?

Comment: can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an `UISwitch` is calling back into managed code. It's likely:

- calling into an object that has been garbage collected (it's freed and can't be used anymore). Ensuring you kept a reference to the object being used would solve this; or
- it could also be calling an UI element out of the main thread. Ensuring UI elements are only used form the main thread would solve that case.

Hopefully this will help you. If not we'll need to see some source code in order to help you further. You can edit your question to add it.